# Spring Cloud Dataflow app/stream default properties

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I specified in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://configserver:8888
```

but when I deploy a stream from the dashboard I can see in the logs

> Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888

which means that it still tries to use the default settings.

Also any other properties like Kafka binder or zkNodes are not read from `application.properties`, but the default values are used, which makes the deployment to fail.

How can I override these properties for all the deployed app/streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties must be prefixed with `spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream`, like

```
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.config.uri=http://configserver:8888
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka:9092
spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zookeeper:2181
```